# Differentiate between vertical and horizontal image format jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to differentiate if an image is vertical or horizontal format and add a special class. I'm use this to fill my div fully with my image.

My HTML:

```
<a href="images/gallerie/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" class="impression">
    <img src="images/gallerie/image-1.jpg">
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.wide {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.tall {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My JS (jQuery):

```
$('.impression').find('img').each(function() {
    if($(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1) {
        $(this).addClass('wide');
    }

    else {
        $(this).addClass('tall');
    }
});
```

It works only sometimes, and I don't know why.
On my iPhone it works never (Chrome).

Has anybody an other solution or maybe the reason why it works sometimes?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making sure that your images are loading before your jquery executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a load event handler so image is loaded before you can check dimensions

```
$('.impression').find('img').on('load',(function() {
    // image is loaded now
    if($(this).width() / $(this).height() > 1) {
        $(this).addClass('wide');
    }

    else {
        $(this).addClass('tall');
    }
});
```

The `each` is not needed as jQuery will use `each` internally and `this` will be image instance

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you are running the function too soon and your images have not been loaded yet. In order to make sure, you can always `console.log()` the values of `.width()` and `.height()`.

The best way to make sure the image has loaded when you check its dimensions is to use the `load` event.

```
$('img').on('load', function(){
  // do your thing...
})
```

The rest is  wrong, as pointed out by @charlietfl. The `load` event for `img`'s does not propagate.

<strike>Better yet, instead of binding a listener to each `img`, just bind one on `body` for all your images, including the ones you will load later on, using some fancy async method:</strike>

```
$('body').on('load', 'img', function(){
  // do your thing...
})
```

This second version will run every time an `<img>` will `load` in your DOM, not only when you run the `script`.

Comment: You're wrong to think that. None of us was born coding. You're asking and learning. You're smart. :)

Comment: are you sure load event propagates? i've never tried that

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure, but I believe it does. Not necessarily because I remember testing it, but because I'm pretty sure I used it like this on many occasions and I assume something would have failed at some point if it didn't. The best way I can think of testing this, is by loading an image with `XHR`. I'll get back after I test.

Comment: Lukas, you should really mark @charlietfl's answer as correct. Wasn't it good for your specific use case?